# Preload Key Request for font files

Tags: wordpress, testing, performance-testing, web-performance

I have searched on internet and found if i Consider doing something `<link rel=preload>` it will fix the problem.

but i dont find these resources in my code files can one help me to find source of these files so that i can modify them?

[My Website](https://hardware.a-tek.org)

[image]

Note: I am using wordpress website and the theme name is **kuteshop** if you want to see any other file let me know.

Looking forward to hear your valuable responses.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding following code in my wordpress function.php fixed the issue.

```
function font_preload() {
                
                 echo '<link rel="preload" href="http://mywebsite.org/wp-content/themes/kuteshop/assets/fonts/Pe-icon-7-stroke.woff?d7yf1v" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">';
                  echo '<link rel="preload" href="http://mywebsite.org/wp-content/themes/kuteshop/assets/fonts/flaticon/Flaticon.woff" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">';
                  
                  echo '<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc4.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">';
                  echo '<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc4.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">';
                  echo '<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v18/1Ptxg8zYS_SKggPN4iEgvnHyvveLxVs9pbCIPrE.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">';
                  echo '<link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v18/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous">';
                  
                  
                  
        }
        add_action('wp_head', 'font_preload', 0);
```

Comment: Hi where did you find out about this? Could you share a resource please?